# Select From a table that is constantly being inserted into

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, insert, deadlock

How would I go about grabbing data from a table that is CONSTANTLY being inserted into (and needs to be) without causing any locking so that the inserts will continue unheeded.

I've looked around and found select with nolock option but, if I'm understanding correctly, this does not stop the lock creation, rather goes around current locks and grabs everything?

Thanks.

EDIT: This table will never be UPDATED, only INSERTS and SELECTS

Comment: While using `NOLOCK` or `NO COMMIT` level will work for this (although you will likely get dirty reads), you should be able to safely use `READ COMMITTED` (or equivalent).  Because you're not updating, you shouldn't have an issue with lock contention (it's going to skip everything that's been inserted, but not yet committed).

Comment: Yeah and dirty reads is definitely something I do not want as this process will be fairly important.  I've found that I'll be doing about 250 inserts per minute from multiple sources and I want to make sure those inserts continue on without getting blocked by my select.  I'm not planning to index as the index will be quickly fragmented (or so I believe)

Comment: I'm not up on how they're implemented (and I've never used SQL Server), but I think your `Clustered Index` (especially over something like a `rowId` or `insertTimestamp`) may index in a non-fragmentory way (anybody else able to weigh in on this?).

Comment: I really need to get my facts straight but the guy who knew was out to lunch, its around 500 to 600 inserts per minute :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you don't mind getting dirty reads from your table this shouldn't be a problem for you. Make sure that the translation isolation level is set appropriately and that your calling code (if applicable) isn't using implicit transactions and you should be fine.

Microsoft's Transaction Isolation Docs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

NOLOCK is a common, and in my opinion, abused option when running into situations like this. Although it can help you overcome problems in high contention situations it can also cause  difficult to track down bugs. Although this is something of an ongoing argument check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx for an idea of some of the risks with using hints like this.

Comment: Hmm... so using nolock can cause huge issues from missing data completely.  This is an important piece that can't have something like this occur.  Is there no way to select the data I want while inserts continue to function unhampered?

Comment: @Antares - You mention elsewhere that you're expecting an insert into the table every second or so. If this is truly the case (60 inserts a minute or so) you shouldn't have any problem issuing a select in that time frame. The default isolation level, READ COMMITTED, will prevent dirty reads and at 60 inserts a minute should be able to operate fine. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122.aspx Are you actually seeing a problem in practice or are you just planning ahead?

Comment: I'm just planning ahead.  Currently each server has its own database to write to, however, we will be moving to one central database which all these servers will be writing to.  I was mistaken at the volume of inserts we're doing, on average, during peak hours, we do about 250 inserts per minute.  So, not only do I want to make sure that the SELECT not cause any problems, we're going to have 7 servers writing to this one table at a rate of 35 per minute.

Comment: I was again mistaken but I now I know this is correct since I've confirmed with the one who knows.  It'll be around 500-600 inserts per minutes.

Comment: @Antares - You're still well within SQL Server's capabilities (I'm assuming you're using Enterprise). If you migrate the other servers to the central database and notice performance degradation you can start to track down inefficiencies in usage.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the NOLOCK hint when selecting from the table. There are some side effects like this (you can basically get a dirty read.)

NOLOCK issues no row locks in the query you add it to, and has no impact on the locks issued by other running queries. NOLOCK does issue a a Sch-S lock, Schema Stability lock, which isn't going to cause you a problem.

Comment: Thank you, so I'll need to use the nolock option but is there a way to prevent the dirty uncommitted pieces?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have misunderstood. select ... with (nolock) will *not* acquire any locks. That is to say, it will not block any other writes.

The downside seems to be that it will include uncommitted reads, so the result may not hold it the writing transaction rolls back.

Comment: Hmm so there is no way to read only committed rows while not blocking the table during a select?

Answer (score 1):

You can use NOLOCK, but I would only recommend that in cases where you know that "dirty data" is acceptable (for example, a syslog database where you know data will never be altered or deleted once it's been inserted).  The best way to do it is to SELECT from data that is NOT being locked; can you identify rows that aren't being affected by your insert?  For example, if your data is being inserted with a CreateDate column defaulting to GETDATE(), make sure your queries pull data from BEFORE that point.

Of course, it all depends on how much data is being written and whether or not the insert statement is generating row or page or table locks...

Comment: I believe it's going be an INSERT every second or so.

Comment: My mistake, after running the numbers, we average about 250 inserts per minute.

Answer (score 1):

One option not discussed here is to use replication. If you replicate the table in question and run your queries on the replicated database, you will not block inserts/updates. (In your case, I would use transactional replication - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176.aspx).